# How to as mouseover to Line Graph Interactive in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and was trying to make a simple Interactive Line Graph. My current code: http://jsfiddle.net/9xske0m1/
is based off of one found on bl.ocks.org

I was thinking about adding a vertical line like the one here: http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2657838 but with the values of the lines displayed as a legend in a hover over, as opposed to having them displayed on the bottom of the chart, and I when I hover over a line.
So I was wondering how I would go about doing that.
I am assuming I have so add some thing around here:

```
    data = data.map( function (d) { 
    return { 
      CAUSES: d.CAUSES,
      YEAR: parseDate(d.YEAR.toString()),
      VALUE: +d.VALUE }; 
});   


// then we need to nest the data on CAUSES since we want to only draw one
// line per CAUSES
  data = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.CAUSES; }).entries(data);


  x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values, function (d) { return d.YEAR; }); }),
             d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.YEAR; }); })]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.VALUE; }); })]);

  // var path1 = svg.append("g").append("path").data([data1]).attr("class", "line1");


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  var causation = svg.selectAll(".CAUSES")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d.key; })
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "CAUSES");

  causation.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDITS**

For those finding this answer through a search, also see [the answer I wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34887578/16363).  It's a very similar question with a much cleaner implementation.

---

I didn't look at the implementation of the linked example but recreated the effect.  I went a little over the top playing around with this, so before I explain here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xske0m1/4/).

Essentially I added a vertical line to follow the mouse.  I also added a `g` of a `circle` and `text` element for each plotted line.  When you mouse over the plot, I update the vertical line to the mouse position, figure out where the vertical line is on the x-axis and determine where it intersects each plotted path.  Finally, I updated the position of the circle and update the text elements with the interpolated x,y positions.

Here's a commented explanation of the added code:

```
svg.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
  .attr("class","mouseLine")  
  .style("stroke","black")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px")
  .style("opacity", "0");

var mouseCircle = causation.append("g") // for each line, add group to hold text and circle
      .attr("class","mouseCircle"); 

mouseCircle.append("circle") // add a circle to follow along path
  .attr("r", 7)
  .style("stroke", function(d) { console.log(d); return color(d.key); })
  .style("fill","none")
  .style("stroke-width", "1px"); 

mouseCircle.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)"); // text to hold coordinates

var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.YEAR; }).right; // reusable bisect to find points before/after line

svg.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
  .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .on('mouseout', function(){ // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouseLine")
            .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouseCircle circle")
            .style("opacity", "0");
      d3.selectAll(".mouseCircle text")
            .style("opacity", "0");
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(){ // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        d3.select(".mouseLine")
            .style("opacity", "1");
         d3.selectAll(".mouseCircle circle")
            .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouseCircle text")
            .style("opacity", "1");
  })
  .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
      d3.select(".mouseLine")
      .attr("d", function(){
          yRange = y.range(); // range of y axis
          var xCoor = d3.mouse(this)[0]; // mouse position in x
          var xDate = x.invert(xCoor); // date corresponding to mouse x 
          d3.selectAll('.mouseCircle') // for each circle group
              .each(function(d,i){
                 var rightIdx = bisect(data[1].values, xDate); // find date in data that right off mouse
                 var interSect = get_line_intersection(xCoor,  // get the intersection of our vertical line and the data line
                      yRange[0], 
                      xCoor, 
                      yRange[1],
                      x(data[i].values[rightIdx-1].YEAR),
                      y(data[i].values[rightIdx-1].VALUE),
                      x(data[i].values[rightIdx].YEAR),
                      y(data[i].values[rightIdx].VALUE));

              d3.select(this) // move the circle to intersection
                  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + interSect.x + ',' + interSect.y + ')');

              d3.select(this.children[1]) // write coordinates out
                  .text(xDate.toLocaleDateString() + "," + y.invert(interSect.y).toFixed(0));

              });

          return "M"+ xCoor +"," + yRange[0] + "L" + xCoor + "," + yRange[1]; // position vertical line
      });
  });

// from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968345/16363
function get_line_intersection(p0_x, p0_y, p1_x, p1_y, 
    p2_x, p2_y, p3_x, p3_y)
{
    var rV = {};
    var s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
    s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;     s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
    s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;     s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

    var s, t;
    s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    t = ( s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

    if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
    {
        // Collision detected
        rV.x = p0_x + (t * s1_x);
        rV.y = p0_y + (t * s1_y);
    }

    return rV;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I was wondering how I would go about making it display just the Year and the exact value from the CSV for the mouse-over?

Comment: @EddieCheung, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xske0m1/5/).  I've updated it to answer your question.