# How to make a mouseover interactive line graph with multiple data series and 2 y axes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know this is a simple problem - something similar was solved in these questions: [Multiseries line chart with mouseover tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886070/d3-js-multiseries-line-chart-with-mouseover-tooltip?lq=1) and [How to as mouseover to Line Graph Interactive in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440455/how-to-as-mouseover-to-line-graph-interactive-in-d3) .
I tried to use the code from the first situation for a similar visualization. The original datafile is in csv, in a format like

```
date    m_total_calories    rhr
20160101    2792    72
20160102    2047    65
20160103    2201    62
20160104    2624    67
20160105    2169    64
20160106    3011    59
20160107    1893    62
20160108    3035    56
20160109    1946    57
```

In my visualization, I'm using 2 axes, so I have to define the variables in a slightly different way. As you can see below, I have variables line_l and line_r that are visualized, and they should be referred to by the object "lines". I tried defining it as an array, but it didn't work. Do you know what could the solution be?

(I apologize for asking such a simple question, I'm new to JavaScript.)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Data from Jawbone UP3 </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> <center> Data collected by Jawbone UP3 </center> </h1>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.tip"></script>
<script>


function myFunction() {
    d3.csv('2016_up.csv', draw);}

function draw(data) {
    "use strict";
    var margin = 60,
        width = 950 - margin,
        height = 475 - margin;
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.m_total_calories = +d.m_total_calories;
    d.rhr = +d.rhr;
});

var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.date}))
    .range([margin, width]);

var y_left_scale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.m_total_calories}))
   .range([height, margin]);

var y_right_scale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.rhr}))
   .range([height, margin]);

var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x_scale)
    .orient("bottom");

var y_axis_left = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y_left_scale)
    .orient("left");

var y_axis_right = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y_right_scale)
    .orient("right");


var line_l = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return x_scale(d.date);})
    .y(function(d){return y_left_scale(d.m_total_calories);});

var line_r = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return x_scale(d.date);})
    .y(function(d){return y_right_scale(d.rhr);});


d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width+margin)
    .attr("height", height+margin)
  .append('g')
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('d', line_l)
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("fill", "none");

d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('d', line_r)
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("fill", "none");

d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(x_axis);

d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + ",0)")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .call(y_axis_left)

  .append("text")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Calories burned")

d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .call(y_axis_right)

  .append("text")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Average heart rate")

  ;

    // var mouseG = svg.append("g")
  var mouseG = d3.select("svg").append("g")
       .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

     mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
       .attr("class", "mouse-line")
       .style("stroke", "black")
       .style("stroke-width", "1px")
       .style("opacity", "0");

     // THIS IS PROBLEMATIC
     var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

     var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
       .data(data) //   cities)
       .enter()
       .append("g")
       .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

     mousePerLine.append("circle")
       .attr("r", 7)
       .style("fill", "none")
       .style("stroke-width", "1px")
       .style("opacity", "0");

     mousePerLine.append("text")
       .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

     mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
       .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
       .attr('height', height)
       .attr('fill', 'none')
       .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
       .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
         d3.select(".mouse-line")
           .style("opacity", "0");
         d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
           .style("opacity", "0");
         d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
           .style("opacity", "0");
       })
       .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
         d3.select(".mouse-line")
           .style("opacity", "1");
         d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
           .style("opacity", "1");
         d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
           .style("opacity", "1");
       })
       .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
         var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
         d3.select(".mouse-line")
           .attr("d", function() {
             var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
             d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
             return d;
           });

         d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
           .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
             console.log(width/mouse[0])
             var xDate = x_scale.invert(mouse[0]), // x.invert(mouse[0]),
                 bisect = d3.bisector(function(data) { return data.date; }).right,    //d) { return d.date; }).right;
                 idx = bisect(data.values, xDate);

             var beginning = 0,
                 // HERE COMES A PROBLEM WITH LINES DEFINITION
                 end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                 end = 100,
                 target = null;

             while (true){
               target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
               // HERE COMES ANOTHER PROBLEM WITH LINES DEFINITION
               pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
               if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                   break;
               }
               if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
               else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
               else break; //position found
             }

             d3.select(this).select('text')
               .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

             return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";
           });
              });

</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Show me the Graph! </button>


</body>
</html>
```

I would be really grateful if someone could give me some advice / help me find a solution. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your data is in a different format then the linked question and you haven't accounted for it.  Mainly you have a single array with both y datapoints in it where the other question had an array of arrays.  In addition, the "problematic" line is because you haven't assigned a class to the lines for the selection later one.  Finally, I also took the liberty of re-factoring a little bit of the code, particularly the initial plot set-up (no need to `d3.select('svg')` over and over).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Data from Jawbone UP3 </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> <center> Data collected by Jawbone UP3 </center> </h1>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      //d3.csv('2016_up.csv', draw);
      var data = "date,m_total_calories,rhr\n20160101,2792,72\n20160102,2047,65\n20160103,2201,62\n20160104,2624,67\n20160105,2169,64\n20160106,3011,59\n20160107,1893,62\n20160108,3035,56\n20160109,1946,57";
      draw(d3.csv.parse(data));
    }

    function draw(data) {
      "use strict";
      var margin = 60,
        width = 950 - margin,
        height = 475 - margin;
      var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.m_total_calories = +d.m_total_calories;
        d.rhr = +d.rhr;
      });

      var x_scale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.date
        }))
        .range([0, width]);

      var y_left_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.m_total_calories
        }))
        .range([height, 0]);

      var y_right_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.rhr
        }))
        .range([height, 0]);

      var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient("bottom");

      var y_axis_left = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_left_scale)
        .orient("left");

      var y_axis_right = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_right_scale)
        .orient("right");


      var line_l = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x_scale(d.date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y_left_scale(d.m_total_calories);
        });

      var line_r = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x_scale(d.date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y_right_scale(d.rhr);
        });


      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin)
        .attr("height", height + margin)
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + 0 + ")");

      svg
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('d', line_l)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("fill", "none");

      svg
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('d', line_r)
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .style("fill", "none");

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(x_axis);

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .call(y_axis_left)
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", 30)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Calories burned");

      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .call(y_axis_right)
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", 30)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Average heart rate");

      // var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      var mouseG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

      mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
        .attr("class", "mouse-line")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("opacity", "0");

      // THIS IS PROBLEMATIC
      var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

      var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
        .data([0,1]) //   cities)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

      mousePerLine.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 7)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
        .style("stroke", function(d,i){
          return (i === 0) ? "steelblue" : "red";
        })
        .style("opacity", "0");

      mousePerLine.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

      mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
        .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
        .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .style("opacity", "0");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
            .style("opacity", "0");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
            .style("opacity", "0");
        })
        .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .style("opacity", "1");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
            .style("opacity", "1");
          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
            .style("opacity", "1");
        })
        .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
          var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
          d3.select(".mouse-line")
            .attr("d", function() {
              var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
              d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
              return d;
            });

          d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {

              var beginning = 0,
                end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                target = null,
                pos = null;

              while (true) {
                target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                  break;
                }
                if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                else break; //position found
              }
              
              var y = (i === 0) ? y_left_scale : y_right_scale;

              d3.select(this).select('text')
                .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

              return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
            });
        });
    }
  </script>

  <button onclick="myFunction()"> Show me the Graph! </button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much, Mark!